# I want to plot mAP and loss graphs during training of YOLOv3 Darknet object detection model on Google colab

Tags: python, user-interface, object-detection, yolo, darknet

I want to plot mAP and loss graphs during training of YOLOv3 Darknet object detection model on Google colab. I think google colab does not have a GUI that's why it does not display any graphs.

i tried anyway and used this command to plot the graphs during training:

```
!darknet/darknet detector train custom_data/labelled_data.data darknet/cfg/yolov3_custom.cfg custom_weight/darknet53.conv.74 -map
```

also this at the end of the training to evaluate each weights :

```
!darknet/darknet detector map custom_data/labelled_data.data darknet/cfg/yolov3_custom.cfg backup/yolov3_custom_2000.weights
```

and tried this during training an other time  :

```
!/darknet/darknet detector train data/obj.data yolo-obj.cfg yolov4.conv.137 -dont_show -mjpeg_port 8090 -map
```

but none of these commands worked for plotting Loss nor mAP graphs showed up...
this the only information that i have during training:
"1: 640.424744, 640.424744 avg, 0.000000 rate, 3.913164 seconds, 64 images"
Please help this is extremely frustrating..

Answer (score 2):

To make things clear, there will be no separate window to show the progress of loss and mAP on a chart for Colab, unfortunately.

To make sure everything's working, try the following:

1. Add `-dont_show` whenever you train in Colab because there's no display screen.

Run this command:

```
!./darknet detector train custom_data/labelled_data.data cfg/yolov3_custom.cfg custom_weight/darknet53.conv.74 -dont_show -map
```

2. You might have missed the location of `chart.png` under the darknet folder. If you have compiled darknet under `./content`, the structure will be as follows:

[image]

3. Put your output log in a txt or log file:

   !./darknet detector train custom_data/labelled_data.data cfg/yolov3_custom.cfg custom_weight/darknet53.conv.74 -dont_show -map | tee output.log

You will see the detailed output in `output.log` under the darknet folder in this case.

Comment: I always use -dont_show yes.
There is no chart.png in my colab or drive.. i searched everywhere.
And if i try the log.txt, only loss is found in the text, (next mAP will be calculated in 1000 iterations). I want it to be calculated every 100 iterations.

Comment: @OubaidGharbi try changing the burn in value in cfg file from 1000 to 100.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. I eventually edited the burn value, but this was a year ago. Thank you !